# Chrome extension attach properties to each tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In a chrome extension, I've created tab properties that I'm trying to store with each tab. What is the best way to do this? I've looked into using localStorage, but it seems like there could be an easier way. The data is by no means permanent, it only exists as long as the tab does.

Comment: You can probably create an "array" that the key is the tab id and the content is what you want

Comment: Yeah, that would work actually. I would probably have to have a cleanup script on tab closed so that the array wouldn't balloon with a lot of tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's definitely no need to use `localStorage`. Without the notion "data is by no means permanent", one already knows that: tab IDs are unique within a session. From this fact, it follows that the data is non-persistent.

The best method to implement it is to maintain a hash of tab properties:

- [`chrome.tabs.onCreated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated) (optional,  add initial info to tab hash)
- [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) - (Add/) Update tab hash (URL is available)
- [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onRemoved) - Remove hash entry

[Tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) objects are not expensive: All properties are primitives (booleans, numbers, strings).

For instance (background page only):

```
var tabStore = {};         // <-- Collection of tabs
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    tabStore[tabId] = tab;
});
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(function(tabId) {
    delete tabStore[tabId];
});
```

Comment: I was just trying to work this out my self yesterday and after a day of messing around with local storage came to the exact same conclusion. Glad to know I finally ended up in the right place! Thanks :)

Comment: Note that for each "page life cycle", `onUpdated` is fired twice (`changeInfo.status`: loading, complete). So, if you want to act only once on a page change event, ignore one of them, eg `if (changeInfo.status != 'loading') {/*...do whatever you want..*/}`.

Comment: Thankfully for me (can't speak for OP) I don't need the onUpdated event, but good info :)

Comment: Can these values assigned to the tabsStore accessible at the popup page ?

Comment: Yes, using `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`, which returns a reference to the background's `window` object.

Comment: Note that the tab being added to the hash is a copy of the real tab object. To save some space, you could just set the hash to whatever additional properties you need to add to the tab (`tabStore[tabId] = { newTabProperty: value };`) , and access the standard/existing ones from the actual tab object itself using tabs.query or other appropriate API mechanism. Although, making a full copy allows a nice synchronous access to the tab properties.

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT ADDENDUM to Rob W's answer.

Make sure to also listen to tabs.onReplaced as well, and update the tabStore accordingly.

```
chrome.tabs.onReplaced.addListener(function(addedTabId, removedTabId) {
    tabStore[addedTabId] = tabStore[removedTabId];
    delete tabStore[removedTabId];
});
```

Chrome can change the id of a tab under the hood without warning or signs. As far as I know, the only place that this happens is the Google "instant search" when you type in a search into the address bar. It may be an edge case, but if you don't track this, it could end up being a very insidious problem.