# chrome-extension: get url of activated tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs

I've deleted a question of mine because it seemed to be a duplicate question. But actually I think I came up with an answer that districts my question from the other one.

My original question:
I was wondering if there is a straight way to find out the url of a tab that was activated. I'm asking since the object parameter passed to the handler function of [chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onActivated) doesn't contain the url of the activated tab as [onUpdated.addListener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated)'s handler, for example, does.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112270/chrome-extension-attach-properties-to-each-tab) is an optional answer but I was looking for a simpler one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer linked in the question works for the general case of tracking tabs properties.

However, for that particular case of onActivated, since it's about the currently active tab, you can simply use `chrome.tabs.getSelected`:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(object activeInfo) {

   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
      var url = tab.url;
      //do something
   });
});
```

What do you say?

Comment: You don't need to use onActivated to simply retrieve the url of the active tab; getSelected(null) (or [chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true})](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) since [getSelected is deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16)) will do that for you. You only need onActivated to run code when the active tab changes.

Comment: You're right, but what I needed is to grab the url of the tab as it becomes active. What I want to point out is that even though the `object activeInfo` doesn't contain that, it can be retrieved with a single line of code. Thanks for the `chrome.tabs.query` tip though.

Comment: @JeffreyYasskin, if you think that my question is not well worded, I'll restate it.

Comment: I think your answer is better than the one you link in the question. Storing the urls in a hash in onCreate/onUpdate has the problem, that if the user has tabs opened before installing the extension, these will not be saved, and you will not be able to get them in onActivated.

Answer (score 0):

That's an old question but for some others who needs the latest information, here's the latest version with [Jeffrey Yasskin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943619/jeffrey-yasskin)'s code.

### Fetching currently active tab

```js
// background.ts or background.js

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(getCurrentTabInfo)

async function getCurrentTabInfo() {
  try {
    // the result of tabInfo is an 'Array'
    const tabInfo = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
    // the result `tabInfo[0]` includes url, faviconUrl, etc...
    console.log(tabInfo[0])
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("An error occured!")
  }
```

And permissions should be added as well

```json
// manifest.json

{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",       // <------------ added
    "activeTab"   // <------------ added
  ],

}
```