# Getting around <meta> X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, x-frame-options

I'm writing a chrome extension that like [intab](http://iansilber.com/intab/) loads links in an inline iframe, it works great except for sites that set the X-Frame-Options header to DENY or SAMEORIGIN.

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15532791/593425) a working solution provided for the case where the HTTP header contains X-Frame-Options property. But, X-Frame-Options can also be set in a  element in the HTML .

Is there a way to remove this element before it's being loaded by chrome?

Answer (score 0):

## `<meta name="X-frame-options"/>`

There is no such thing as `<meta name="X-Frame-Options">`. 
And, manipulating the DOM before chrome loads it, is also not possible.
 Chrome loads a page, and then creates the dom.

## But what are `x-frame-options` then?

X-frame-options are server-side set http headers.
They are part of the security protection (e.g. against clickjacking). Chrome or any other browser will not let you ignore/change it. Period.
*Side note:if it's your site, you can change x-frame-options per PHP.*
*Side note #2: the only way to do this is  [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). I'm pretty sure you don't want to do that.*

Comment: Is no one paying attention in here?       If this answer is bad, just comment, don't ignore it.