# Invisible tabs in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I basically want to automate a website by using a Chrome extension. But this website has extremely much client-side code, so it's really hard to find out which request I need to make in order to get the needed information.

The easiest way I can think of would be to use a content script to enter text in input elements and click buttons, like this (with jQuery in this case):

```
$.ready(function(){
  $("#input").val("foo");
  $("#submit").click();
});
```

Quite similar to this question: [Injecting input into a tab opened by a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121939/injecting-input-into-a-tab-opened-by-a-chrome-extension), but the interaction with that website should not be visible.

So: Can I open pages in chrome from an extension, that are not visible to the user and use them to interact with websites?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome extension: loading a hidden page (without iframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299322/chrome-extension-loading-a-hidden-page-without-iframe)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want the page to be completely invisible, I believe that the only option is to load it into an iframe on the background page. You can then access the page within the iframe using content scripts, just as you would access any normal visible page.

Since many sites limit embedding using the `X-Frame-Options` header, you will likely have to use the webRequest API to remove that header before loading the page into an iframe. Some pages also use other techniques to prevent embedding that might further complicate this.

**Example code:**

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hidden page in background",
  "description": "Interact with a hidden page in background",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.google.fr/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["*://*.google.fr/*", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]
}
```

***background.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe1" width="1000 px" height="600 px" src="http://www.google.fr"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

***background.js***

```
// This is to remove X-Frame-Options header, if present
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
    function(info) {
      var headers = info.responseHeaders;
      var index = headers.findIndex(x=>x.name.toLowerCase() == "x-frame-options");
      if (index !=-1) {
        headers.splice(index, 1);
      }
      return {responseHeaders: headers};
    },
    {
        urls: ['*://*.google.fr/*'], //
        types: ['sub_frame']
    },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

***contentscript.js***

```
var elementToInsert = document.createElement("h1");
elementToInsert.textContent = "This text comes from my content script.";
document.body.insertBefore(elementToInsert, document.body.firstChild);
```

**Couple of notes:**

- The removal of `X-Frame-Options` header is not limited to the background page here. It would allow embedding of the relevant page in iframes on any other page as well. Unfortunately, Chrome does not seem to support the `ALLOW-FROM uri` value that could be used to limit embedding to your extension only.
- Content script is being injected to all pages here. You could inject it programmatically only to the iframe on the background page, but that gets a bit more complicated.
- I used `www.google.fr` as an example, because it uses `X-Frame-Options`, but does not use any other techniques to prevent embedding. I used the French domain because `google.com` tends to redirect to local country-level domains automatically.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. In my case I surprisingly don't even need to remove the X-Frame-Options header.

Comment: V3 only supports service workers now. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

See [tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create), you could call the following code creating an invisible tab (not active).

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: 'https://www.google.com', active: false, });
```

Comment: This is still a visible tab.

Comment: What I would like to do could normally be done with a headless browser, but not in a chrome extension.

Comment: Use chrome.windows.create with "popup" and you'll have a headless browser.

Comment: Not working as of Oct 2022

Comment: I think putting anything except extension pages in `url` violates "API Use" Chrome Web Store Policies https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/program-policies/api-use/

Anyone tried publishing extension with such code?