# err_file_not_found error in loading a page in extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load the same link of the tab into the popup window (this is not my primary purpose and i am doing this just to get acquainted) I am getting the error

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

My js file is as follows

```
var pageGenerator = {
    requestPage: function() {
        var urlTosearch;
        chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(w) {
            chrome.tabs.getSelected(w.id,
            function (response){
                urlTosearch = response.url;
            });
        });
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", urlTosearch, true);
        req.onload = this.loadPage_.bind(this);
        req.send(null);
    },
    loadPage_: function (e) {
        var resp = e.target.responseText;
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', resp);
    }
};
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   pageGenerator.requestPage();
});
```

I have read that external pages can not be loaded onto the popup. Is it so? If true why? and if not how can it be done?

Comment: Use iframes - http://julip.co/2010/01/how-to-build-a-chrome-extension-part-3-loading-any-web-page-in-a-popup/

Comment: Still the same error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND chrome-extension://donolbgicbohlegccfjljabmnoadgmec/undefined

Comment: Try console.log the response.url to ensure that it is indeed defined

Comment: `urlTosearch` will be undefined when you call `req.open`. See this question: [Why is my variable undefined after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: yes the url is defined yet somehow the page is not getting loaded.I got an xframe error which says Refused to display  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. Then referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension I followed the answer with 15 up votes yet the issue does not resolve. I am getting the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onHeadersReceived' of undefined . Please help

Comment: Are the files listed as [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources)?

Answer (score 3):

When receiving **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND**  you probably didn't defined your url correctly. Since i don't see your url in your piece of code and i see no accepted answer i will share what i think goes wrong.

At first you have to define the url you are posting in your manifest with:

```
"permissions": [
  "http://www.yoururl.com/"
],
```

Also when calling your api by: yoururl.com/ the chrome extension will not call the api. Just simply because it thinks the url is withing the scope of your extension locally. To solve this you have to define `http://www`. or `https://www`. Now Chrome will recognize you try to load something from outside of the extension.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `Active Tab` permission ***FROM A BACKGROUND script*** in order the get the URL of the current page.  Then use `chrome.tabs.create()` to open a new tab with that same URL.

Details here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab