# Chrome extension: getting around frame restrictions on facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, google-chrome-extension, xss

I am working on an extension called [Web Panel](https://addons.opera.com/sv/extensions/details/web-panel/?display=en) (actually it's an Opera extension, but the API is the same as the one in Chrome). Basically it allows the user to view a web page in an iframe. The problem is that many sites don't want this to happen, for example with x-frame-options. I already use this workaround: [Getting around X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension), but the problem is that it doesn't work on all sites, for example facebook. I have tried to remove the content-security-policy header as well, which actually made it work on github, but still not on facebook.

So, my three thoughts are:

- What header should i remove to make it work?
- Now I'm using chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived. Can it be that I have to use chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders for example to remove any header?
- Or is facebook using some other method for doing this? I know they simply can check if the window is top level by doing `window == window.top`, and then perhaps load content based on the condition. Can I modify the window variable somehow?

Comment: These restrictions are in place for good reasons. _“Basically it allows the user to view a web page in an iframe”_ – and the purpose of that would be what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe Opera has a side bar for putting different extensions in it (http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2015/06/view-tabs-easier-get-sidebar-extensions-opera-30/). The old version of Opera had like a bulit in extensinon for viewing websites in the sidebar, so it becomes like a split screen. As they do not have this left, I made an extension.