# Chrome extension: Load content of remote page inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load an external webpage inside an iframe. The external webpage includes javascript and html.

When I try to load the iframe, I get the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Here is the content script code

```
let iframeEl = document.createElement('iframe');
iframeEl.src = "https://www.example.com";
document.body.appendChild(iframeEl);
```

How can I get past the cross origin error?

Comment: Why not? Simply create an iframe element in the content script and assign its `src` property.

Comment: you'll also need to inject a `content script` (with `"all_frames": true`) into the `iframe` page to do the `postMessage` stuff, but it's definitely possible to do what you need

Comment: The main issue is that when I do, I get the error "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin ...". Essentially, cross origin leads to failure.

Comment: @dipole_moment, then show us the code and error (i.e. supply a [MCVE].)

Comment: @wOxxOm I am getting a cross origin error.

Comment: @dipole_moment, the posted code does not access the iframe so the error is caused by something else. Use the devtools debugger.

Comment: You may want to check suggested workaround given in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame) and see if it will help you. As mentioned, you can work on this problem using `window.postMessage` and its relative message event to send messages between the two pages.

Comment: please see answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension/15534822#15534822