# Chrome extension: override nonconfigurable properties

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What's the easiest solution to override nonconfigurable properties?

---

Contentscript `Object.defineProperty` too can't override nonconfigurable properties. Sample:

```
d=document
d.documentElement.appendChild(_=d.createElement('iframe'))
Object.defineProperty(_.contentWindow,'top', {configurable:true})
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: top
>       at Function.defineProperty ()

Comment: For what it's worth, the research I did to find an answer for you leads me to believe that this is impossible. But maybe someone knows a way.

Comment: `window.top` is unforgeable as per spec.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Doesn't the spec applies only to web JS [--not chrome JS]?

Comment: No such thing as chrome JS. Every modern browser implements the spec.

Comment: @KarlReid, What solution did you use in the end?

Comment: @Pacerier there is no solution, that's what I said. Sorry if you misread.