# X-Frame Options Not 100% For Blocking Iframes

Tags: security, iframe, x-frame-options

It seems setting X-Frame-Options to deny is the most recommended method to prevent my website from being Iframed.   But it is not perfect.  First off X-Frame-Options can be ignored by using a Chrome extension as discussed in the below post.  I have proved this is the case by using the Ignore X-Frame headers chrome extension.

[Getting around X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension)

Secondly X-Frame-Options deny only works on the first iframe of a web page, if I iframe a web page twice the second iframe works.

My question is, what is the best multipronged approach to prevent my website from being iframed?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the second iframe works"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Frame-Options is just a response header. Of course if you control the client, you can ignore it. If you control the client, you can do pretty much anything.

The point in X-Frame-Options is to prevent attacks like [Clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) (primarily) or [Pixel Perfect Timing Attacks](https://www.contextis.com/resources/white-papers/pixel-perfect-timing-attacks-with-html5) for example. It does indeed prevent those attacks, because the attacker cannot control the victim's browser to say install an extension (or if he can, Clickjacking is the least issue from the victim's perspective :) ).

Comment: Thank you for your response.   You stated "if you control the client, you can ignore it", does that mean if a user (client) has a chrome extension installed that extension has control of the clients computer?

Comment: Well, an extension can't do anything, but it has a lot of control over webpages loaded in the browser, it may have some level of access (maybe limited I guess) to the filesystem, etc. I'm not an expert in extensions, and it may differ by browser, so have a look at docs! But an extension definitely does have access to webpages in the browser if the user grants that access, it can read and modify them, can get any data entered by the user in pages, etc.

Comment: @Garbor thank you again.  As far as preventing my site from being iframed is the X-Frame-Options the best approach?

Comment: @user1609391 I would say yes, because it's very simple and compatible. A newer but somewhat more complex alternative is [Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors). If you are unsure, go for X-Frame-Options.