# opening tabs/windows without displaying them

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Using a Chrome extension, I wish to extract information from a large number (20 to >100) of pages all linked to from a list in one page, and then present that compiled info on a new page created by the extension. The original page with the link list and its linked subpages are not owned by me and I cannot influence their settings in any way.

In a previous similar situation, I have managed to solve this by creating one `<iframe>` element for each subpage and setting the styles for those iframes to `{display:none;}` such that the extension's page doesn't get visually cluttered while it extracts the desired info. This time however, I get the error message `Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.` The iframe approach thus seems doomed here.

Therefore I tried the more brutal option to temporarily create a new *tab* for each subpage using `window.open();` . It works, but it looks horrible, what with scores of tabs being generated instantly. Is there any operation I could make on the tabs corresponding to the css hiding of the iframes, such that the generated tabs are not shown? Because of security limitations, cURL won't work.

**Subsequent edit:**
The stated question, about hiding tabs, I guess is answered in the negative; however, the problem that made me pose that question (the header restrictions against putting content in iframes) was solved by the answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension).

Comment: I actually doubt that you can instruct a browser to make a new tab and not show it but somehow have it exist. Imagine the security problems if this was allowed.

Comment: Are you positive you can't use [XHRs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) to get the information instead?

Comment: @ChrisG: I can get the primary output from the subpages using jQuery `$.get()` but those data are not the final page contents – they are mainly strings of calls to external javascripts, like `<script src="static-d12676b59025bff1b2251df5f5e417c6/ng/ladok/ladok.js"></script>`. I do not know how to go from there to the actual page without letting the browser render the page in an iframe (not possible here) or a window/tab. Do you?