# hostname for extension to allow Iframing?

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, microsoft-edge

I want to allow iframe to be loaded in my extension.

I am creating and extension which will wrap one other app in the iframe. For that app to allow iframing inside that extension I need to give hostname on which I can iframe the app.

What is the hostname for an extension ?

what about across edge and chrome ?

PS: one solution which we already have is to intercept response headers and remove the IFRAMING headers , but I am also exploring how to get the hostname for the extension so that we can configure this on server side.

Comment: Instead of allowing it you can simply [strip the header that disallows it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15532791/getting-around-x-frame-options-deny-in-a-chrome-extension).

Comment: hey thanks a lot , that is what we were thinking right now, but just wanted to test the server side thing as well, as that somehow seem more clean. but let me edit the question to mention that we are already considering that option as well.

Comment: Do you want to pass hostname to extension? And the hostname is your host name, or the domain? In addition, what is the relationship between extension and server isde?