# Replacement for Chrome App that can embed websites with X-Frame-Options: DENY?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, google-chrome-app

I have a desktop Chrome App that acts as a dashboard, and simply embeds 4 sites in `webview`s. Unfortunately Chrome Apps are deprecated so I'm wondering what I can use instead.

I was looking into Progressive Web Apps but it necessitates `iframes`, which don't work as the sites supply `X-Frame-Options: DENY` (not under my control unfortunately).

What is the best way of displaying 4 3rd party sites in a window, with minimal chrome (as in UI clutter)?

Comment: [Getting around X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15532791)

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, looks like that in conjunction with https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/migration/#build-extension-web-page might be the way to go