# Origin is changed in Chrome Extension Service Worker Fetch Request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Hi I am developing chrome extension for social media marketing. I am using fetch in service_worker to send a request on facebook but but it is not working for me.

When I copy this request as fetch Request from network requests then paste it on facebook page, it works perfectly.

The difference is that origin-header is overridden in while sending this request in service-worker thats why it doesn't work for me.

I am using this code to change the headers but this is also not working for me.

```
await chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
 (details) => {
       let { requestHeaders } = details;
       const headerList = {};

       for (let i = 0; i < requestHeaders.length; i += 1) {
           if (requestHeaders[i].name === 'Origin') {
               requestHeaders[i].value = 'https://m.facebook.com';
               break;
           }
       }

       headerList.requestHeaders = requestHeaders;

       return headerList;
   }, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"])
```

Can you please elaborate how should I use webRequest.onbeforeSendHeaders to change headers. If I have to use declarativeNetRequest, how should I use it.

I am using Manivest Version 3 BTW.

Comment: webRequest can't change headers in ManifestV3. You must use declarativeNetRequest as shown in the documentation. You can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69177790) by changing the `operation` to `set` and header name accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules to override the headers

Here is the code.

```
await chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules(
    {
        addRules: [{
            "id": 1,
            "priority": 1,
            "action": {
                type: 'modifyHeaders',
                requestHeaders: [
                    { header: 'origin', operation: 'set', value: "https://www.facebook.com" }
                ],
            },
            "condition": { "urlFilter": "facebook.com", "resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest"] }
        }
        ],
        removeRuleIds: [1]
    },
)
```

You also have to provide permissions to use declarativeNetRequest in manifest.json