# Is there a way to allow content Script iframe to requests with all cookies it has to in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am woorking on an extention that is intented for personal use. It purpose is to render a widget on everypage with my keep.google.com notes as an iframe.

So far I have been able to follow thos [stackoveflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69177790/6842763). And I have reached somewhere where I get an error  `accounts.google.com redirected you too many times.` But I realised this error is only on the brave browser and I can go in the privacy settings and `Allow all cookies` insteady of `Block third-party cookies` and make it work.

Is there a way around this problem? Can I get it working without temparing with brave settings?

I currently have  a